# Using scanf to accept user input

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.2

I was reading an article about scanf. I personally have never checked the return code of a scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buf[64];
  if(1 == scanf("%63s", buf))
  {
    printf("Hello %s\n", buf);
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Input error.\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am just wondering what other techniques experienced programmers do when they use scanf when they want to get user input? Or do they use another function or write their own?

Thanks for any suggestions,

EDIT =========

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input_buf[64] = {0};
    char data[64] = {0};

    printf("Enter something: ");
    while( fgets(input_buf, sizeof(input_buf), stdin) == NULL )
    {
    /* parse the input entered */
    sscanf(input_buf, "%s", data);
    }

    printf("Input [ %s ]\n", data);

    return 0;
}
```

I think most programmers agree that scanf is bad, and most agree to use fgets and sscanf. However, I can use fgets to readin the input. However, if I don't know what the user will enter how do I know what to parse. For example, like if the user was to enter their address which would contain numbers and characters and in any order?

Comment: Never checking the return code from any of the input routines is always dubious in the extreme - you must be lucky.  The short answer is "I don't use `scanf()` or `fscanf()`; I occasionally use `sscanf()` but tread warily".

Comment: After updating my answer. How would you normally use sscanf to parse the data. If you are not sure what the data the user will be inputing? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `scanf` directly.  It's surprisingly hard to use.  It's better to read an entire line of input and to then parse it (possibly with `sscanf`).

Read this entry (and the entries it references) from the comp.lang.c FAQ:
http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Edit:
Okay, to address your additional question from your own edit: If you allow unstructured input, then you're going to have to attempt to parse the string in multiple ways until you find one that works.  If you can't find a valid match, then you should reject the input and prompt the user again, probably explaining what format you want the input to be in.

For anything more complicated, you'd probably be better off using a regular expression library or even using dedicated lexer/parser toolkits (e.g. flex and bison).

Comment: Hello, I have updated my answer. But I am not sure about the parsing using sscanf? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I don't use `scanf()` for interactive user input; I read everything as text using `fgets()`, then parse the input as necessary, using `strtol()` and `strtod()` to convert text to numeric values.

One example of where `scanf()` falls down is when the user enters a bad numeric value, but the initial part of it is valid, something like the following:

```
if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1)
{
  // process num
}
else
{
  // handle error
}
```

If the user types in "12e4", `scanf()` will successfully convert and assign the "12" to num, leaving "e4" in the input stream to foul up a future read.   The *entire* input should be treated as bogus, but `scanf()` can't catch that kind of error.  OTOH, if I do something like:

```
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
{
  int val;
  char *chk;
  val = (int) strtol(buffer, &chk, 10);
  if (!isspace(*chk) && *chk != 0)
  {
    // non-numeric character in input; reject it completely
  }
  else
  {
    // process val
  }
}
```

I can catch the error in the input and reject it before using any part of it.  This also does a better job of not leaving garbage in the input stream.

`scanf()` is a great tool *if* you can guarantee your input is always well-formed.

Comment: Hello. Say you wanted the user to input their address. Which would have numbers and letters. You could read in the input using fgets. But how would you parse the input. I think you could just read it into a buffer using fgets and that would be it. I can't see how you would use sscanf for this. Thanks.

Comment: I would treat a mailing address as all text, potentially broken up into several fields (address, street name, city, state, ZIP, etc.).  When and how I would tokenize it would depend on the application (such as if I needed to search for records based on ZIP code or street name or something).  If all I need to do is store it for display later, I probably wouldn't even bother tokenizing it.

Answer (score 2):

scanf()  has problems, in that if a user is expected to type an integer, and types a string instead, often the program bombs. This can be overcome by reading all input as a string (use getchar()), and then converting  the string to the correct data type.

```
/* example one, to read a word at a time */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXBUFFERSIZE   80

void cleartoendofline( void );  /* ANSI function prototype */

void cleartoendofline( void )
{
    char ch;
    ch = getchar();
    while( ch != '\n' )
        ch = getchar();
}

main()
{
    char    ch;                     /* handles user input */
    char    buffer[MAXBUFFERSIZE];  /* sufficient to handle one line */
    int     char_count;             /* number of characters read for this line */
    int     exit_flag = 0;
    int     valid_choice;

    while( exit_flag  == 0 ) {
        printf("Enter a line of text (<80 chars)\n");
        ch = getchar();
        char_count = 0;
        while( (ch != '\n')  &&  (char_count < MAXBUFFERSIZE)) {
            buffer[char_count++] = ch;
            ch = getchar();
        }
        buffer[char_count] = 0x00;      /* null terminate buffer */
        printf("\nThe line you entered was:\n");
        printf("%s\n", buffer);

        valid_choice = 0;
        while( valid_choice == 0 ) {
            printf("Continue (Y/N)?\n");
            scanf(" %c", &ch );
            ch = toupper( ch );
            if((ch == 'Y') || (ch == 'N') )
                valid_choice = 1;
            else
                printf("\007Error: Invalid choice\n");
            cleartoendofline();
        }
        if( ch == 'N' ) exit_flag = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I make a loop call fgets until the end of the line is read, and then call sscanf to parse the data.  It's a good idea to check whether sscanf reaches the end of the input line.

Answer (score 1):

I rarely use `scanf`.  Most of the times, I use `fgets()` to read data as a string.  Then, depending upon the need, I may use `sscanf()`, or other functions such as `strto*` family of functions, `str*chr()`, etc., to get data from the string.

If I use `scanf()` or `fgets()` + `sscanf()`, I *always* check the return values of the functions to make sure they did what I wanted them to do.  I also don't use `strtok()` to tokenize strings, because I think the interface of `strtok()` is broken.