# Recurring error within loop C

Tags: c, loops

I just have a loop that returns to the start if a invalid option has been entered

```
    do{                     
        printf("Please enter a option, Press 'q' to quit\n"); 
        scanf("%d",&option);

        if(option == 1){
            option1(...);
            break;
        }else if(option == 2){
            option1(...);
            break;
        }else if(option == 3){
            option1(...);
            break;
        }else if(option == false){
            printf("exit\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    } while(true);
```

My problem is

If I run it and enter a input eg: '5' it returns to the start of the do statement and I have to enter another input.

If I enter 'q' to quit the loop goes crazy and keeps repeating itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using scanf to accept user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144459/using-scanf-to-accept-user-input)

Comment: What type is `option`? And why are you comparing it to `false`?

Comment: You could read them as characters (char) and compare them to characters '1', '2', 'q'. Beware newline characters.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to quit the program using `q`, you should declare variable `option` as char.

---

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char option;
    do
    {                     
        printf("Please enter a option, Press 'q' to quit\n"); 
        scanf(" %c",&option);

        if(option == '1')
        {
            //option1(...);
            printf("%c",option);
            break;
        }
        else if(option == '2')
        {
            //option1(...);
            printf("%c",option);
            break;
        }
        else if(option == '3')
        {
            //option1(...);
            printf("%c",option);
            break;
        }
        else if(option == 'q')
        {
            printf("exit\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    } while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The 'q' is not read with `scanf("%d"...`. `option` therefore probably has none of the values switched over, so that the default case is executed which repeats the loop. That's what you see.
Remedy:

1. Any non-numeric input means break: Just leave everything as is but change `continue` to `break` and exit the loop.
2. Catch non-numerical input and handle it. The scanf manual page (http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) says:

   > These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
   >   and assigned

   You could check the scanf return value and, if 0, try to scanf the letter in another statement; if 'q', break.
3. Read a char right away (seems cleanest) and switch over the char, not the int value represented by it.