# understanding of format specifier integer (%d)

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the format specifier `%d`, below is the example

When I tried to take two 4 digit number as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("Enter two 4 digit numbers!\n");
    scanf("%2d %2d", &x, &y);
    printf("Display %d %d", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Enter two 4 digit numbers:
6789 4321
Display: 67 89
```

Here, I am not able to point why this is printing from `x`.

Comment: Why do you use `%2d` as format?

Comment: you have a matching failure, check the return value of scanf.

Comment: The code you show should not even compile. Please make sure that you post *actual* code.

Comment: use `scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);`

Comment: oh, right...fixed

Comment: Furthermore, is your question about the format for `scanf` or for `printf`?

Comment: Please post code that actually compiles

Comment: int main()
{
    int x,y,temp;
    printf("Enter two 4 digit number!\n");
    scanf("%2d %2d",&x,&y);
    printf("Display %d %d ",x, y);
    return 0;
}

On GNU GCC v7.1.1

Comment: ...in the question, not in comments

Comment: @SouravGhosh I checked the output of scanf, it is returning 2.  I think it is wrong. 

If it wrong, then how we can scan 4 digit or 2 digit integer using scanf. Any idea?

Comment: @CrazyCoder main.cpp(8): error C3861: 'printf': identifier not found
main.cpp(9): error C3861: 'scanf': identifier not found
main.cpp(10): error C3861: 'printf': identifier not found

Comment: @CrazyCoder what's wrong with `scanf("%d, %d", &x, &y);`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I want to strict scanf to take only 2 digit integer.

Comment: @CrazyCoder do you want 2 digit numbers or 4 digit numbers? Your code doesn't match the text "Enter two __4__ digit numbers". Please clarify.

Comment: @Jabberwocky just I am trying to understand the behavior of %2d or %4d.

Answer (score 3):

Your code, containing

```
scanf("%2d %2d", &x, &y);
```

tries to read two 2-digit integers from your input

```
6789 4321
```

`67` is a 2-digit integer which gets stored in `x`, `89` is a 2-digit integer that gets stored in `y`. The rest of the input remains in the buffer of `stdin`.

Your assumption

> I am not able to point why this is printing from x

is wrong because

```
printf("Display %d %d ", x, y);
```

not only prints "from x" but it prints `x` and `y`.

To read two 4-digit integers use

```
scanf("%4d%4d", &x, &y);
```

Comment: As per your answer when I will put scanf("%2d, %4d", &x,&y);
it should be print as 67 8943. but it is printing 67 89. why?

Comment: I take it you didn't mean to put that comma in the format string between `%2` and `%4` ... given the input `6789 4321` the `%2` reads two digits `67` and the `%4` reads `89` which is followed by whitespace. Whitespace can't appear inside an integer so `scanf()` is done.

Comment: @CrazyCoder because with `"%2d %2d"`, and input `1234 5678` the first 2 chars (`12`) match the first `%2d` and the next 2 chars (`34`) match the second `%2d`. `scanf` is not really suitable for user input. Read [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2144498/898348)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Crazy one asked about `"%2d %4d"`.

Comment: Thank you @Swordfish I got it.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: note that white space (blanks, tabs, newlines) in a `scanf()` format string indicate _optional_ white space in the input stream. Also (as others have said), `%2d` reads _at most_ 2 decimal digits; `%4d` reads _at most_ 4 decimal digits; both will be OK with fewer digits. Any unread characters are left for the next input. Thus, when it reads `67` for the first `%2d`, the `8` and `9` are still in the input; the blank in the format string matches zero spaces, and the second `%2d` reads the next two digits (`%4d` reads the two digits and the space, but leaves the space in the input).

Answer (score 0):

you should not use "," or space inside `scanf`. You can simply write as

```
scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
```

Comment: that seems to have both "," and spaces in it.  Can you explain what you meant more clearly?

Comment: The commas or dots are not wanted, but the spaces are harmless (but unnecessary).  White space in a `scanf()` format specifier means 'zero or more white space characters'.  Most conversion specifiers already skip leading white space (`%c`, `%[…]` and `%n` are the only ones that do not), but the white space can make the format easier to read, and can occasionally be important.  The punctuation (`.` or `,`) has to be matched explicitly in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `scanf("%2d %2d", &x, &y);` reads 2 integers alright. But what's the catch here is that, each integer can be at most 2 digits long. If anything longer is given as input, it would consider the first 2 digits as part of the first integer, and the **next 2 characters** as part of next integers. The remaining part of the input is just stored buffer without affecting the input variables.

Here is a demonstration:

> Enter two 4 digit numbers:
>
> 6789 4321
>
> Display: 67 89  //takes `67` as 1st integer, next 2 chars(`89`) as the
>   next one

..

> Enter two 4 digit numbers:
>
> 678 9876
>
> Display: 67 8   //observe the
>   change--> `67` is the first integer, `8[space]` is taken as the next
>   one(though the `[space]` is ignored when being stored as `int`, it is
>   considered while extracting as input).